# Clearing out data from knockout observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have the below model

```
self.newItem = ko.observable({
    manufacturer: ko.observable(),
    itemnumber: ko.observable(),
    itemDescription: ko.observable(),
    priceclass: ko.observable(),
    currentPrice: ko.computed(function () {
        return "1.22";
    }, this),
    aeAuthority: ko.computed(function () {
        return "1.02PC";
    }, this),
    requestedMinimumQuantity: ko.computed(function () {
        return "!.22 PC";
    }, this),
    RequestedPrice: ko.observable(),
    ExpirationDate: ko.observable(),       
    ItemDetails: ko.observable(),
    Margin: ko.observable(),
    Status: ko.observable()

});
```

I want to clear out the data inside this observable but when I do `self.newItem = ""; or self.newItem('');` but that removes all the observables inside the newItem so there is no property left inside newItem. I can go inside and clear each observable inside newItem individually but is there a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how do remove all items from new Item and then put in a an empty Item so they can update it??

Comment: Define "clear out". Also, describe what functionality you are trying to implement. It's very likely that you are trying to do something that is better solved in a different way.

Comment: By clear out I mean making all the  observables inside newItem empty like manufacturer = ''. I have  it mapped inside a modal dialogue form so when the form closes I want to empty the new item so all the fields that are mapped to data like manufacturer or itemnumber becomes empty.

Comment: Why don't you simply generate a new viewmodel when you need a new modal? That would be the way to do this in knockout. A lot easier than writing extra code to reset an existing viewmodel. But you can of course combine `ko.utils.objectForEach()` and `ko.isWritableObservable()` to make a loop that overwrites all observable properties on an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *iterating* method in Knockout, you'll have to write one yourself. Typically I'd recommend using constructor functions, where plenty of options are available for what you want (the specific implementation would depend on requirements).

However, to answer your question "straight up", here's the easiest way to "clean out" all data in observable properties inside another observable:

```
function clean() {
  var item = self.newItem();
  for (var key in item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isWriteableObservable(item[key])) {
      item[key](null);
    }
  }
};
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.newItem = ko.observable({
    manufacturer: ko.observable("Some manufacturer"),
    itemnumber: ko.observable("12345"),
    itemDescription: ko.observable("A nice item"),
    priceclass: ko.observable("High"),
    currentPrice: ko.computed(function () {
        return "1.22";
    }, this),
    aeAuthority: ko.computed(function () {
        return "1.02PC";
    }, this),
    requestedMinimumQuantity: ko.computed(function () {
        return "!.22 PC";
    }, this),
    RequestedPrice: ko.observable(1.25),
    ExpirationDate: ko.observable(new Date()),       
    ItemDetails: ko.observable("Comes with a thingie"),
    Margin: ko.observable(0.25),
    Status: ko.observable("Available")
  });
  
  self.clean = function() {
    var item = self.newItem();
    for (var key in item) {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isWriteableObservable(item[key])) {
        item[key](null);
      }
    }
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
pre { font: 11px consolas; padding: 5px; background: #fafafa; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: clean">clean out everything</button>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good way to achieve clearing your Models. With the help of `ko.simpleMap`, you can assign a new value to your existing model in your viewModel with default value. It uses `Array function` [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). You can also use this in scenario where you get the data from the server then apply value to you existing viewModel. You can also use `ko.simpleMap` to JS Object as a `source`.

```js
(function(){
    ko.simpleMap = function(source, target, excludedFields){
        excludedFields = excludedFields || [];

        for(var key in source){
            if(!source.hasOwnProperty(key) || key[0] === "_" || excludedFields.some(function(excludedField) {
                return excludedField.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase();
            }))
                continue;
            var targetKey;
            if(!Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target).some(function(tempKey) {
                if(tempKey.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()){
                    targetKey = tempKey;
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }))
                continue;

            var sourceValue;

            if(typeof source[key] === "function")
                sourceValue = source[key]();
            else
                sourceValue = source[key];

            if(typeof target[targetKey] === "function"){
                if(ko.isWriteableObservable(target[targetKey]))
                    target[targetKey](sourceValue);
            } else
                target[targetKey] = sourceValue;
        }

        return target;
    };

})();

function MyModel(){
    this.manufacturer= ko.observable();
    this.itemnumber= ko.observable();
    this.itemDescription= ko.observable();
    this.priceclass= ko.observable();
    this.currentPrice= ko.computed(function () {
        return "1.22";
    }, this);
    this.aeAuthority= ko.computed(function () {
        return "1.02PC";
    }, this);
    this.requestedMinimumQuantity= ko.computed(function () {
        return "!.22 PC";
    }, this);
    this.RequestedPrice= ko.observable();
    this.ExpirationDate= ko.observable();       
    this.ItemDetails= ko.observable();
    this.Margin= ko.observable();
    this.Status= ko.observable("Approved");

}

var viewModel = {
  item: new MyModel(),
  clear: function(){
    ko.simpleMap(new MyModel(), this.item);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: item.manufacturer" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.manufacturer"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.itemnumber" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.itemnumber"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.itemDescription" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.itemDescription"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.priceclass" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.priceclass"></span><br/>
<span data-bind="text: item.currentPrice"></span><br/>
<span data-bind="text: item.aeAuthority"></span><br/>
<span data-bind="text: item.requestedMinimumQuantity"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.RequestedPrice" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.RequestedPrice"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.ExpirationDate" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.ExpirationDate"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.ItemDetails" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.ItemDetails"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.Margin" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.Margin"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: item.Status" type="text" /><span data-bind="text: item.Status"></span><br/>
<button data-bind="click:clear">Clear</button><br/>
```